# $.when with arrays of functions is not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, .when

**Problem that I'm trying to solve:** I want to have two arrays of ajax functions. One with topPriority that should run first, and another one with low priority that will start as soon as ALL of the topPriority calls are done.

However, this functions are not even called in the `$.when` line. Am I using this correctly?

//Html:

```
<div id="foo">Hello World</div>
```

//CSS:

```
#foo{ border:1px solid red; padding:10px; display:none }
```

//Javascript:

```
// open your console!

function getData(){
   return $.get('/echo/html/');
}

function showDiv(){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $('#foo').fadeIn( 1000, dfd.resolve );

    return dfd.promise();
}

var topPriorityFunctions = new Array();
topPriorityFunctions.push(showDiv);
topPriorityFunctions.push(getData);

$.when.apply($, topPriorityFunctions )
    .then(function( ajaxResult ){
        console.log('The animation AND the AJAX request are both done!');

        // ‘ajaxResult’ is the server’s response
        // start my lowPriorityTasks.
    });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/1167/) is the fiddle with all this code in order to be able to test it an modify it.

References: I tried to modify from the working example on this [page](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery) in order to solve my problem.

Comment: Don't pass `dfd.resolve` directly as the callback. `resolve()` will be invoked with `this` bound to `$("#foo")[0]` instead of `dfd`, which will most probably break the implementation. Pass an anonymous function that calls `dfd.resolve()` instead.

Comment: Note: you can change `$('#foo').fadeIn( 1000, dfd.resolve )` to simply `return $('#foo').fadeIn(1000).promise()` as that will return the animation queue promise

Comment: thanks @frédéricHamidi. I don't understand quite well you explanation. Why are my functions not even called? I really don't care to much about the function showDiv being a Deferred object, since my problem is actually a bit different. ALL of my functions are just ajax calls.

Comment: @cacho, looks like a fiddle problem. With jQuery (edge), my browser says `Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"`. With jQuery 2.1.0 the functions are called.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, assuming no other animations are started on `#foo` during the 1 second delay, yes.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: True. It will depend on the specific case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidim, I have updated the jsfiddle to reflect the code posted in my questions. I can't get it to work with JQuery 2.1 either :O/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) does not accept or expect an array of functions, it expects an array of *deferreds*. You need to invoke your functions, and pass the promises in.

```
var topPriorityPromises = [];
topPriorityFunctions.push(showDiv());
topPriorityFunctions.push(getData());

$.when.apply($, topPriorityPromises ).then(function () {
  // ...
```

If you simplify this and ignore the array/apply portions, you would be invoking `when` this way, which is wrong:

```
$.when(showDiv, getData);
```

*not* this way, which is correct:

```
$.when(showDiv(), getData());
```

Comment: thanks @meagar. The thing is I actually do not need a Deferred function, I just have an array of 10 ajax calls. But, I need 3 of them to finish first (top priority), and then I want to call the rest of the 7 ajax calls (low priority).

Comment: In that case, can I still use $.when.apply( ) with an array of ajax calls functions?

Comment: You have 3 urls which can work independently and other 7 depends on accumulated response of first 3. Is that what you want?
BTW check this as well..https://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/1168/

Comment: @Vishwanath no, actually ALL of the requests can run independently. I just want to give 3 of them a TOP priority because I want them to complete first.

Comment: @cacho That has nothing to do with $.when or the code you've posted in your question. You cannot use `$.when` to "boost" the priority of your AJAX calls. Just *do them first*. My answer answers the question you asked, which is why `$.when` doesn't invoke your functions. If you want to start discussions around this priority concept, ask a new question.